# Почему стили на bootstrap не подключаются правильно, фреймворк laravel

Tags: bootstrap, laravel, классы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую navbar-toggler, но стили не все используются, почему. Ответ, если можно поточнее[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Подключение стилей bootsrap в laravel в файле resources/assets/sass/app.scss :

`// Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`

Если Js и CSS собраны корректно(https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend), то кнопка `navbar-toggler` в bootstrap 4 согласно вашей верстке должна появиться при ширине экрана меньше 768px.

`@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
}`